# For any metric space $(X,d)$ with $X$ finite, there exists an isometric embedding $f:X\rightarrow R^4$

Tags: real-analysis

For any metric space $(X,d)$ with $X$ finite, there exists an isometric embedding $f:X\rightarrow R^4$?

I have no idea to proceed for the problem. Please help

Comment: Judging from this: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12394/representability-of-finite-metric-spaces it doesn't seem possible to always achieve this for arbitrary finite metric spaces. Are you sure you aren't missing some conditions?

Comment: The best distortion one can guarantee for embeddings into $R^4$ is approximately $\sqrt{|X|}$ up to a logarithmic factor.

Comment: Now that if $X$ is the discrete metric space on 6 points (that is, all the pairwise distances are 1), then $X$ doesn't isometrically embed into 4-dimensional Euclidean space.

Comment: What metric do you use on $R^4$?

Comment: usual metric.........

Comment: The smallest (cardinality-wise) example that does not embed in **any** Euclidean space is a certain metric on the 4-element set.